# how to configure Kafka-Python client.dns.lookup = "use_all_dns_ips"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-python

I want to configure my python producer/consumer with client.dns.lookup = "use_all_dns_ips"
but none of python kafka clients like kafka-python (2.0.1) and confluent-kafka (1.3.0) support this

This is how i have generating producer object

```
producer = KafkaProducer({
'bootstrap_servers': [localhost:1234,localhost:1235,localhost:1236],
"client.dns.lookup" = "use_all_dns_ips"
})
```

I got below error message

```
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such configuration property: "client.dns.lookup""}
```

Is there a way to use this config?

Comment: Are you running your Kafka inside Docker? Can you specify how you are running Kafka?

Comment: Yes, kafka is running inside docker

Comment: Are you running your application inside or outside of docker container?

Comment: Also could you share your docker file?

Comment: I am running my job as a separate pod, where kafka is also running in another pod

Comment: Have you tried creating github issues with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka-python(2.0.1) and confluent-kafka(1.3.0) neither supports **client.dns.lookup** option. Please refer to the list below.

**Kafka-python(KafkaProducer) support option list**

url : https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html

- bootstrap_servers
- client_id (str)
- key_serializer (callable)
- value_serializer (callable)
- compression_type (str)
- retries (int)
- batch_size (int)
- linger_ms (int)
- partitioner (callable)
- buffer_memory (int)
- connections_max_idle_ms
- max_block_ms (int)
- max_request_size (int)
- metadata_max_age_ms (int)
- retry_backoff_ms (int)
- request_timeout_ms (int)
- receive_buffer_bytes (int)
- send_buffer_bytes (int)
- socket_options (list)
- reconnect_backoff_ms (int)
- reconnect_backoff_max_ms (int)
- max_in_flight_requests_per_connection (int)
- security_protocol (str)
- ssl_context (ssl.SSLContext)
- ssl_check_hostname (bool)
- ssl_cafile (str)
- ssl_certfile (str)
- ssl_keyfile (str)
- ssl_password (str)
- ssl_crlfile (str)
- ssl_ciphers (str)
- api_version (tuple)
- api_version_auto_timeout_ms (int)
- metric_reporters (list)
- metrics_num_samples (int)
- metrics_sample_window_ms (int)
- selector (selectors.BaseSelector)
- sasl_mechanism (str)
- sasl_plain_username (str)
- sasl_plain_password (str)
- sasl_kerberos_service_name (str)
- sasl_kerberos_domain_name (str)
- sasl_oauth_token_provider (AbstractTokenProvider)

**Confluent-kafka(KafkaProducer) support options list**

url : https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

- transactional.id
- transaction.timeout.ms
- enable.idempotence
- enable.gapless.guarantee
- queue.buffering.max.messages
- queue.buffering.max.kbytes
- queue.buffering.max.ms
- linger.ms
- message.send.max.retries
- retries
- retry.backoff.ms
- queue.buffering.backpressure.threshold
- compression.codec
- compression.type
- batch.num.messages
- delivery.report.only.error
- dr_cb
- dr_msg_cb
- request.required.acks
- acks
- request.timeout.ms
- message.timeout.ms
- delivery.timeout.ms
- queuing.strategy
- produce.offset.report
- partitioner
- partitioner_cb
- msg_order_cmp
- compression.codec
- compression.type
- compression.level
- builtin.features
- client.id
- metadata.broker.list
- bootstrap.servers
- message.max.bytes
- message.copy.max.bytes
- receive.message.max.bytes
- max.in.flight.requests.per.connection
- max.in.flight
- metadata.request.timeout.ms
- topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms
- metadata.max.age.ms
- topic.metadata.refresh.fast.interval.ms
- topic.metadata.refresh.fast.cnt
- topic.metadata.refresh.sparse
- topic.blacklist
- debug
- socket.timeout.ms
- socket.blocking.max.ms
- socket.send.buffer.bytes
- socket.receive.buffer.bytes
- socket.keepalive.enable
- socket.nagle.disable
- socket.max.fails
- broker.address.ttl
- broker.address.family
- reconnect.backoff.jitter.ms
- reconnect.backoff.ms
- reconnect.backoff.max.ms
- statistics.interval.ms
- enabled_events
- error_cb
- throttle_cb
- stats_cb
- log_cb
- log_level
- log.queue
- log.thread.name
- enable.random.seed
- log.connection.close
- background_event_cb
- socket_cb
- connect_cb
- closesocket_cb
- open_cb
- opaque
- default_topic_conf
- internal.termination.signal
- api.version.request
- api.version.request.timeout.ms
- api.version.fallback.ms
- broker.version.fallback
- security.protocol
- ssl.cipher.suites
- ssl.curves.list
- ssl.sigalgs.list
- ssl.key.location
- ssl.key.password
- ssl.key.pem
- ssl_key
- ssl.certificate.location
- ssl.certificate.pem
- ssl_certificate
- ssl.ca.location
- ssl_ca
- ssl.crl.location
- ssl.keystore.location
- ssl.keystore.password
- enable.ssl.certificate.verification
- ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm
- ssl.certificate.verify_cb
- sasl.mechanisms
- sasl.mechanism
- sasl.kerberos.service.name
- sasl.kerberos.principal
- sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd
- sasl.kerberos.keytab
- sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin
- sasl.username
- sasl.password
- sasl.oauthbearer.config
- enable.sasl.oauthbearer.unsecure.jwt
- oauthbearer_token_refresh_cb
- plugin.library.paths
- interceptors
- client.rack
- opaque